# How to get name of CKEditor plug-in on onclick() event?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am implementing CKEditor in one of my site and implementing some extra logic on CKEditor where I need name of plug-in on which user is going to click. Is there any method so, that I can get name of plug-in when I click on it.

If there is no exist method for this then, your customize logic is also welcome in JavaScript.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: User cannot click on a plugin. Plugin is just a code structure - it has no visual representation. Please explain more clearly what you meant.

Comment: @Reinmar: for example if user click on image icon (image plug-in) then I what to alert name of that plug-in, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean an image button in the toolbar? And why would you want to know a plugin name?

Comment: @Reinmar : Yes you are right that's what is want. I need to add some custom logic for give plug-in. So that why I need name of plug-in. btw, if I get any identity of plugin onclick than it is also ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most toolbar buttons use [commands](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.commandDefinition), and before command is executed the [`editor#beforeCommandExec`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-beforeCommandExec) event is fired automatically. So what you need is to listen to that even:

```
editor.on( 'beforeCommandExec', function( evt ) {
    console.log( evt.data.name ); // -> e.g. 'image'
} );
```